# mysql query to get random items from 3 categories

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table with 3 types of data (Text, image, video) 
$type column holds the type of the data. (type = 1 for text, 2 for image and 3 for video)

my requirement is need to get random data of 20 records from the table like which it should have 8 texts, 8 images and 4 videos.

also with the result with first 2 records should be image and next 1 video and next 2 texts and again it repeats.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.41-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a MariaDB 10.1 query that will do what you want. It first selects 8 texts, 4 videos and 8 images at random. It then assigns row numbers to each type of data and uses those row numbers to group values together (2 text, 1 video, 2 images) and the [`ELT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/elt/) function to order within the group as image then video then text.

```
SELECT type, value
FROM (
SELECT value, @rn := IF(type = @type, @rn + 1, 1) AS row, @type := type AS type
FROM (
(SELECT type, value
 FROM data
 WHERE type = 1
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 8)
UNION ALL
(SELECT type, value
 FROM data
 WHERE type = 2
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 8)
UNION ALL
(SELECT type, value 
 FROM data
 WHERE type = 3
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 4)
ORDER BY ELT(type, 3, 1, 2)
) d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @type := '') r) v
ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 1 OR type = 2 THEN (row - 1) DIV 2
              ELSE row - 1 END,
         ELT(type, 3, 1, 2)
```

I've made a [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2f565bf9ed0703d9d7b1327e507f6792) that shows this in operation.

Should you upgrade to MariaDB 10.2, you can dispense with the variables and use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/):

```
WITH cte AS 
((SELECT type, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY RAND()) AS row
 FROM data
 WHERE type = 1
 LIMIT 8)
UNION ALL
(SELECT type, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY RAND()) AS row
 FROM data
 WHERE type = 2
 LIMIT 8)
UNION ALL
(SELECT type, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY RAND()) AS row 
 FROM data
 WHERE type = 3
 LIMIT 4)
)
SELECT type, value
FROM cte
ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 1 OR type = 2 THEN (row - 1) DIV 2
              ELSE row - 1 END,
         ELT(type, 3, 1, 2)
```

This query is also demonstrated in my [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2f565bf9ed0703d9d7b1327e507f6792).

Comment: hi, its working and i tried to get all columns on the record. But its not working.
i replace "type, value" to *.

also sorry i have given wrong information (type = 1 for text, 2 for image and 3 for video) but the real type is 
type = 0 for text, 1 for image and 2 for video

Comment: @binuj If you're using the 10.1 query, you **cannot** use `SELECT *` in this line: `SELECT value, @rn := IF(type = @type, @rn + 1, 1) AS row, @type := type AS type` but otherwise it should be ok. 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f2778ecaff46bcecb478b00df2b0747c